# How to link PhysX libraries with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, game-physics, physx

I am new to c++. I am unaware with how to link the PhysX source to my own code. I keep getting "Px.h" or some other file missing. The files exist in their corresponding folders but Xcode can't find them. What do I do? Thank you so much for your help, I am extremely grateful.

Comment: I left an answer for your benefit, however, your question is a little too vague, it needs to be more specific. In addition, I am not sure this is the place to ask this (maybe a more general forum).

Answer (score 0):

I would look up a tutorial on linking: really any library in the Xcode environment. You can search for that here or using your favorite search engine. I am not familiar with Xcode, generally however, you need to specify "include directories" somewhere in the options, as well as a "library directory" and which "library files" need to be linked (`.o` `.so` `.dylib` as far as I can tell on mac). "Include directories" are where `.h` files are located. `.h` files tell the compiler what is inside `.o` `.dylib` and `.so` files which are "binary files" like your executable is.

If you were compiling from command line with gcc, it would look something like this

`g++ Main.cpp -I /path/to/include -L /path/to/lib -l PhysX.so PhysXSomethingElse.so -o MyExecutable.app`

Comment: Thanks for your help!